# Polymer <paper-input-decorator label="birthday">

Tags: polymer

Is it possible to show the label `birthday` like the other decorators when the input field is empty?

```
<paper-input-decorator label="birthday">
       <core-localstorage name="birthday" value="{{birthday}}"></core-localstorage>
       <input name="birthday" value="{{birthday}}" is="core-input" type="date" required>
</paper-input-decorator>
```

In safari you see a empty field
In chrome a pre defined dd/mm/yyyy
But there is no indication of the label birthday

Comment: Try `<paper-input-decorator label='birthday' floatingLabel labelVisible>`, it might work

Comment: Not really consistent with `type="text"` style but good enough thanks.